# I don't understand how this variable declaration changed in my Queue algorithm exercise?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, queue

I am practicing an algorithm and I got this implementation of a Queue. The problem I am having with this implementation are the lines demarcated by '*'.

The queue correcty works but somehow when I set `this.last.next` to the new value, the `this.first` declaration changes. How is it changing? I'm guessing this has something to do with memory pointers but its really tripping me up. Hopefully that explained it well enough.

I'm just not seeing how `this.last.next` changes `this.first`. I can modify the question if it doesn't make sense. If you run it though with node, you'll see what I'm talking about. Thanks.

```
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class Queue {
  constructor(){
    this.first = null;
    this.last = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  peek() {
    return this.first
  }
  enqueue(value){
    const newNode = new Node(value);

    if (this.first == null) {
      this.first = newNode;
      this.last = newNode;
    } else {

      console.log('first');
      console.log(this.first)
      console.log(this.last)

      ********** Question *******
      How did this line of code change this.first?
      this.last.next = newNode;
      *************************

      this.last = newNode;
      console.log('second')

      *********** Question **************
      Why did this value change? I didn't declare a change
      unless this.last.next was the same as this.first

      console.log(this.first);
      ***************************




      console.log(this.last)
    }
    this.length++;
  }

  dequeue(){
    this.first = this.first.next
    if (this.first === null) {
      this.last = null;
    }
    this.length--;
  }
}

const myQueue = new Queue();
myQueue.enqueue('Joy');
myQueue.enqueue('Matt');
myQueue.enqueue('Pavel');
```

Comment: In `enqueue`, you're creating a *single* new Node, `newNode`. This node is set as both `this.first` and `this.last`. So now the two are pointing to the same Node object. Changing `this.last.next` will consequently change `this.first` (by also setting its `.last`). As far as I can tell, in the `else` block, you need to store `this.last` in a tmp variable, then set it to the new node, then set the tmp's `.next` to the new node.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Chris G. The code as it is right now is complete. It will work, so need for a temp variable. That's what was throwing me off. I think I'm just going to sit on this for a while and I think it will click better for me. I get what your saying though. Thanks.

Comment: Something to consider: in a circular queue, `this.last.next` is by definition equal to `this.first` when the queue is full.